# How to nest async/await functions returned through other functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm trying to create a root promise function (calling an API) that can be reused by other functions to do more specific requests with the API. However the result I get at the end is an incomplete API response. It looks as if it's not "awaiting" the response.

```
// Original API call
const callAPI= async(a, b) =>{
    const url = "https://someapi.com/endpoint/" + a + "/" + b;
    const results = await fetch(url);
    return results
}
// more specific API call using the above function
const specificAPI = async(x) =>{
    const results = await callAPI("abc", x);
    return results;
}
// main
async function main(){
    const results = await specificAPI("123");
    console.log(results);
}
```

The output of the console.log() in the main() function ends up being a fragment of the result. Like its not waiting for the response to return.

Edit: By fragment of the response I meant the response returned looks something like this:

```
{
    date: "2021-05-01",
    body: [
```

Comment: I added that detail above. Basically it looks like I got some of the response but not the rest of if.

Comment: Well `fetch` returns when the browser has received the **start** of the response. Usually you have to also await either the JSON parse (`await result.json()`) or else the raw content (`await result.text()`).

Comment: @xv47 are you saying that fragment is what `console.log(results)` prints?

Comment: @Bergi correct. So I'm getting a response but it's incomplete.

Comment: @xv47 That seems hardly possible with the code you posted. Are you sure `fetch` is the [standard fetch API function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)? Because if so, it should print a [Response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), not a string

Comment: It has nothing to do with async/await but rather it is the design of the `fetch` API. You see, the object that `fetch` returns is not the result. It is a response object. To get the result you need to get the data from that object (eg. `response.json()` or `response.text()`) and that returns another promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the `fetch()` documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch
As you could see it returns a promise of `Response` which isn't your data yet. The data is provided by `response.body` which is `ReadableStream`.
But for your convenience the response provides handy methods to get the data in your preferred format. If you need parsed JSON:

```
// Original API call
const callAPI = async(a, b) =>{
    const url = "https://someapi.com/endpoint/" + a + "/" + b;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return await response.json();
}
```

There's also `response.text()` to get the response data as plain text.
Don't forget to use `try..catch` to handle any errors to display for example a red toast.